# .htaccess How to create a RedirectPermanent by triming a char?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

My goal is to create a permanent redirect

http://example.com/category-/list/town/id/id2/country

to 
http://example.com/category/list/town/id/id2/country

(removing the last '-' char (if present) from category

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*?)-/(.*)$ /$1/$2
```